# No matching function for call to [class]

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

So, I have some classes that I was defining, and it gave me errors for this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;

//void makepayment(int amount, string name, Date date);
//void listpayments();

class Date;

class Date {
  public:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    Date(int month, int day, int year) {
      this->month = month;
      this->day = day;
      this->year = year;
    }
};

class Payment {
  public:
    int amount;
    string name;
    Date date;
    Payment(int amount, string name, Date date) {
      this->amount = amount;
      this->name = name;
      this->date = date;
    }
};

int main() {
cout <<
"|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| \n" <<
"|   WELCOME TO THE       | \n" <<
"|   WESSLES BANK         | \n" <<
"|   MANAGEMENT SYSTEM!   | \n" <<
"|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| \n";

for(;;) {

}

return 0;  
}
```

The error was:

```
foo.cpp: In constructor ‘Payment::Payment(int, std::string, Date)’:
foo.cpp:26:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘Date::Date()’
foo.cpp:26:49: note: candidates are:
foo.cpp:14:5: note: Date::Date(int, int, int)
foo.cpp:14:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
foo.cpp:9:7: note: Date::Date(const Date&)
foo.cpp:9:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I have no idea what is wrong! What does 'no matching function for call' mean?

Sorry if this is a noobie question... I just started c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you've tried to copy an object and there is no default constructor supplied.

```
this->date = date;
```

What you should be doing, is initializing everything in the **initializer list**. There is also no reason you shouldn't be passing some of these arguments by reference.

```
Payment(int amount, const string& name, const Date& date)
    : amount(amount)
    , name(name)
    , date(date)
    {}
```

Same goes for your `Date` class. This will use the compiler generated copy constructor. Be aware that if your class contains more then POD types, you might want to implement your own copy constructor.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I am a java programmer mostly. Just started c++ tody :P.

Comment: No problems. Have fun with C++!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have

```
Date date;
```

in your Payment class, you must have a Date constructor that takes no arguments, i.e. Date::Date(), which you do not have specified.

Answer (score 0):

The Payment class has a Date child. The Payment constructor is first trying to instantiate the Date child with the default constructor, then later assigning a new value to this child. The problem is that the Date child does not have a default constructor Date::Date(). Either give the Date class a default constructor or change the Payment constructor syntax as follows:

```
Payment::Payment(int amount_, string name_, Date date_) : amount(amount_),
    name(name_), date(date_)
{
}
```

Edit: Aesthete beat me to it